# Generated Regex shows error CS8795 in IntelliSense despite the project compiling fine

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a `GeneratedRegex` in my class like so:

```cs
    [GeneratedRegex("...")]
    private static partial Regex MyRegex();
```

IntelliSense shows error CS8795 "Partial method must have an implementation part" and I get a red squiggly line, but the project compiles fine. What does cause this error? It seemingly came out of thin air.

Comment: I see the same. Did you found answer what to do?

Comment: It went away once I switched to .net 8 and updated Visual Studio.